# Is there a way to share games between computers on same network and how do I disable asking for admin permission to run an app?

Tags: file-sharing, privileges

My friend opened a cyber cafe and it's a pain in the ass installing games in each pc, games like fortnite and call of duty 80+gb is taking a lot installing on all pc, is there a way to install all games in a pc and all the other pc have access to them, and second question when I am trying to open a game (pubg) it's asking for admin rights and I can't write password all the time when kids wants to play it, I searched a lot and I can't find a way how to make it available for users with normal access?

Comment: Yes, you can run files from remote locations. No, the performance will suffer significantly when you do this. No, you shouldn't do this. Yes, hard drives are cheap. Also, you've got two questions here. Read the help section. Don't post 2 questions in the same post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Network installation?

### It depends

(I'm coming at this with a background in business application more than games, but the general concepts are transferrable.)

Many applications can run just fine from a remote/network location. For such applications, you can just deploy the executable, and any files that need to go next to it, to an accessible network location, and then deploy a shortcut on each PC.

But many applications need more than that.

- They might need registry entries.
- They might need dlls installed locally.
- They might need a certain version of a framework, such as .NET.
- They are chatty, and thus require more bandwidth (or lower latency) between the PC and the network location than you can provide.

For these applications, you'll often need to install them to each local PC. If it is the cost of the disk space that concerns you, music2myear is right -- drives are cheap enough that you shouldn't be trying to save your pennies there. If it is the time involved in installing the application to dozens (hundreds?) of PCs, you can automate the installation. Nearly all reasonable installers can be scripted such that you can install with just a few clicks. You could even install to a master template and build all of your PCs to inherit that template. (This is probably good idea in a Cyber Café anyway, so you can return a PC to its known-good configuration whenever needed.)

Other pros and cons to the network vs. local install decision include:

- If it is a network install, and something goes wrong, nobody can use the application. If it is a local install, you are more likely to only have one machine at a time unusable.
- Network installs can be easier to update, because you only have to apply the update in one place. But you have to make sure that nobody has the file(s) locked. And that can be a challenge.

## UAC

As music2myear also points out, we want to keep these posts to a single question, so I'll address the UAC part if you ask it separately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Doug, my apologies for posting 2 questions, I just never read terms of use, as for the second question I couldn't find a normal solution I even had microsoft supporters trying to remotely fix it and after 3 -4  hours trying they didn't succeed and I finally found a software which would save the credentials and I wouldn't have to write password anymore